# v-show and other stuff like this does not work on <template>

Tags: vue.js

I try to make a div appear with a `v-show` directive when you click it but nothing works and don't know why...

here's the code :

```
<template>
  <section class="hero is-fullheight homepage-section">
    <columns style="height: 100vh; margin: 0">
      <column v-show="isShow" class="domain-column is-9" position="relative">
        <div class="video-background">
          <div class="video-foreground">
            <iframe
              src="https://XXXX?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&mute=1"
              frameborder="0"
              allowfullscreen
            ></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </column>
      <column
        class="domain-column is-3"
        position="relative"
        style="background: rgba(25, 28, 33, 0.90);"
      >
        <div
          class="columns is-vcentered text-center"
          style="display: flex; color: white;"
          fillheight
        >
          <div>
            <p class="list-item menu-item">
              ABOUT
            </p>
            <p class="list-item menu-item">
              WORK
            </p>
            <p @click="test" class="list-item menu-item">
              POLES
            </p>
            <p class="list-item menu-item">
              CONTACT
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </column>
    </columns>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'homepage',
  data: {
    isShow: true
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log('hello!', this, this.isShow);
      alert('test function => ' + this.isShow);
      this.isShow =  !this.isShow;
    },
    goToPage(domain) {
      this.$router.push(`/${domain}`)
    }
  },

  head() {
    return {
      title:
        'Walter',
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content:
            'Walter'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Can you help me understand why this thing does not happen when I click on it? Event `isShow` change between true and false when `POLES` is clicked.

One more thing for exemple if I do this : hello there : {{ msg }}

msg will not be display.

Comment: Did you try with `v-if` instead? I don't think `iframe` will like `v-show`'s CSS permutation.

Comment: yes I try ```v-if``` and nothing to do...

Comment: what is msg? is vue actually installed and being used? can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: msg is nothing inside the current code but it's just to explain event I got ```msg```in the data and wanna insert a dynamic message into the code it's impossible... quite hard to reproduce it cause I go a lot of npm

Comment: 1. Are you not seeing a console warning about `data` not being a function? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function 2. If you remove the `v-show` entirely, can you see the content? 3. Just for debugging purposes, try putting `{{ isShow }}` next to the text `POLES` so you can see the value of `isShow` in the template. 4. Try inspecting the elements in the developer tools to see exactly what styles are being applied where. `v-show` should manifest itself as a `style="display: none"`. Check whether that toggles when `isShow` changes.

Comment: I trough display ``` {{isShow }} ``` would work but nothing appear so I'm quitte lost cause I test a lot of things to debug it but everything failled... (5 min later) I tried something like add ```console.log(Vue)```into ```test() ``` got the folowing ```ReferenceError: Vue is not defined```

Comment: The identifier `Vue` won't be available in `test` unless you've imported it or made it global. That is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everyone!

I found my mistake! It's a very novice error :

```
data: {
    isShow: true
  }
```

Don't gonna work , I think i understand why. If I use my react notions I could just suppose it's because of the 'state' of the component (WOAW so obvious sorry but it's my first time on vue, I learn about my mistakes) but after few documentations I learn more about vue and `data` like it written above is work as a function and not as an object like I though.

Like this:

```
data() {
    return { isShow: true }
  }
```

In fact that’s because each time you use a component, a new instance of it is created. So the component have him own state so if you got 50 render of the same component they ll have they own properties.
What a big misunderstood but know i figured out what was my problem it's look very logic and natural! I'm happy for that!

Hopefully this response will help some novice like me.

Thx everyone who's tried to help me.